# Tensorflow - Model not learning a regression problem (Addition)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

I am trying to train a model in Keras TensorFlow backend for addition but `mean_absolute_error` is not decreasing its constantly on 
`loss: 42566832.0789 - mean_absolute_error: 42566860.0000`

```
X = np.random.random_integers(100000000,size=(2,10000000))
Y = X[0]+X[1]

X=X.astype('float32')
Y=Y.astype('float32')
X = X.reshape(10000000,2)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128,activation = LeakyReLU()))
model.add(Dense(256,activation = LeakyReLU()))
model.add(Dense(512,activation = LeakyReLU()))
model.add(Dense(128,activation = LeakyReLU()))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="linear"))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics= 
['mean_absolute_error'])
model.fit(X,Y,epochs=1,batch_size=512)
```

Comment: I recommend normalize your data before feeding the model.

Comment: And your model seems to me huge for such task. Imagine one linear neuron with weights=[1, 1] and bias 0 will fit perfectly for this task. If you want to test regression problem I recommend sine wave.